# Rearrange the sentences based on prerequisites

Tags: javascript

I want to rearrange the sentences so that each sentence is a prerequisites for the next sentence and here is what I have and it works fine:

```js
const sentences = [
    "he has eaten a pizza at the party last night",
    "he has eaten a pizza",
    "he has eaten a pizza at the party",
]

function sessionCardsSort(arr) {
    arr = arr.map(part => part.split(' ')).sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
    function sortBy(list, main) {
        return list.sort((a, b) => {
            let count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
            a.forEach(part => { if(main.includes(part)) { count1++ } });
            b.forEach(part => { if(main.includes(part)) { count2++ } });
            return count1 - count2;
        });
    }
    return sortBy(arr, arr[arr.length - 1]).map(part => part.join(' '));
}

console.log(sessionCardsSort(sentences));
```

As you see I used a simple array named `sentences` as data structure to work with, but what if we want to use the same data of `sentences` array with new structure like this:

```
const sentences = [
    { reference: ['he has eaten a pizza at the party', 'last night'] }
    { reference: ['"he has', 'eaten a pizza'] },
    { reference: ['he', 'has', 'eaten a pizza at the party'] },
]
```

So the issue is I want to **implement the exact same function** this time for array of objects not just a simple array!

Here is desired result (only using the exact above function):

```
const sentences = [
        { reference: ['"he has', 'eaten a pizza'] },
        { reference: ['he', 'has', 'eaten a pizza at the party'] },
        { reference: ['he has eaten a pizza at the party', 'last night'] }
]
```

Note: In the second data structure joining elements inside each `reference` will give you the same sentence as the first example, for instance :

```
{ reference: ['he has eaten a pizza at the party', 'last night'] }  

"he has eaten a pizza at the party last night"
```

Note: Please note that I want to **implement the exact same function**

Answer (score 0):

Since the words of each sentence are either a strict subset of another sentence in the set, or the sentence is the largest one, it looks like it'd be a lot easier to just check the strings' overall length instead.

Give each sentence a length property (which is the length of the joined string), and then sort the resulting array of objects by that length, and finally remove the added length property.

```js
const sentences = [
  { reference: ['"he has', 'eaten a pizza'] },
  { reference: ['he', 'has', 'eaten a pizza at the party'] },
  { reference: ['he has eaten a pizza at the party', 'last night'] }
];

function sessionCardsSort(sentences) {
  const sentencesWithLength = sentences.map(
    ({ reference }) => ({ reference, length: reference.join(' ') })
  );
  return sentencesWithLength
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
    .map(({ reference }) => ({ reference }));
}

console.log(sessionCardsSort(sentences));
```

Or calculate the length each time inside the callback - more work (which could be a problem when dealing with huge datasets), but less code.

```js
const sentences = [
  { reference: ['"he has', 'eaten a pizza'] },
  { reference: ['he', 'has', 'eaten a pizza at the party'] },
  { reference: ['he has eaten a pizza at the party', 'last night'] }
];

const toLength = arr => arr.reference.join(' ').length;
const sessionCardsSort = (sentences) => sentences
  .sort((a, b) => toLength(a) - toLength(b));
console.log(sessionCardsSort(sentences));
```

It doesn't look necessary given the input in the question, but if you really need to count words individually, then use a function with similar logic to your current `sortBy` to count up the number of included words.

```js
const sentences = [
  { reference: ['"he has', 'eaten a pizza'] },
  { reference: ['he', 'has', 'eaten a pizza at the party'] },
  { reference: ['he has eaten a pizza at the party', 'last night'] }
];

const toLength = obj => obj.reference.join(' ');
const toWordsIncluded = (obj, mainWords) => obj.reference
  .join(' ')
  .split(' ')
  .reduce((subtotal, word) => subtotal + mainWords.includes(word), 0)
  
const sessionCardsSort = (sentences) => {
  const sorted = sentences
    .sort((a, b) => toLength(a) - toLength(b));
  const mainWords = sorted[sorted.length - 1].reference.join(' ').split(' ');
  return sorted
    .sort((a, b) => toWordsIncluded(a, mainWords) - toWordsIncluded(b, mainWords));
};
console.log(sessionCardsSort(sentences));
```

Comment: No, the algorithm counts the included words not just simply sorting based on length of the sentences.

Comment: It's easy to tweak if you need it, but the data in your question doesn't appear to depend on such logic

Comment: The data is used for ease of understanding, but the main purpose is to "Rearrange the sentences based on prerequisites"

Comment: Thanks for the try, but this is not the exact implementation..

Comment: I get different result ..

Comment: All three of the snippets produce the result you say you wanted in the question. If that isn't actually the result you wanted, please edit your actual desired result into your question.